# Prevent Gmail Address List Sender pop up

Tags: gmail, google-contacts

Is there a method (way) to turn off the Pop Up Box as I move the cursor over email sender's id as I browse emails?  I suffer headaches from flashing objects (like blinking red lights) in one or two seconds.  As I review the emails I must often stop and recover.

Comment: If you have Firefox or Google Chrome I can whip you up a Greasemonkey/Userscript if you'd like?

Answer (score 2):

I had success blocking the popup using the AdBlock Chrome extension.
Right-click on the popup → *AdBlock → Block this ad*.

The filter that seems to be working for me is

```
mail.google.com##DIV[class="tq"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can install the following [Userscript](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/175248) to disable the pop-ups. There is no default option to disable them, so this is really the only way.

Simply use [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) with Firefox, or [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en) with Google Chrome, and then visit the [Userscript](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/175248) page and install the modification.

Using this will disable all the pop-ups for the username.